# How to insert a special character?

Tags: java, char

I need to insert a cent character, how can I do it:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose the number of cents,
"should be the symbol of cents");
```

There should be method with `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java supports Unicode source file:

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose the number of ¢: ");` should work!

Comment: how do I type it in, is there any charGetSymbol(198)...command?

Comment: That depends on your operating system, your keyboard and so on.  A simpler aproach is to find an example and cut-and-paste it.

Answer (score 4):

Java supports Unicode out of the box. Just insert `¢` into the string literal. If that doesn't work, try [`\u00A2`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a2/index.htm).

Comment: I remember I was doing it with \u00A2. I just forgot the method... It was something with char.getSymbol(\u00A2)...something like this...

Answer (score 1):

You are right there is a special command that you can use, I guess it is 169...But Java accepts almost any special characters, so you may simply find it online and copy paste