# Java how to insert a "power of" symbol?

Tags: java

Hello I have a program that displays the area of some land. The number is 1900 square kilometers. I want to write this as 1900 km2 but the two should look like a "to the power of 2" symbol. Is there a way I can insert a symbol like that?

Comment: How? Print to console, or some form of UI, or output in a doc, or what? Java supports unicode. Have you tried just `System.out.println("1900 km²");`?

Comment: Do you mean `^` or you want superscript?

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456002/displaying-fancy-equations-with-java

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Comment: My keyboard has a Shortcut for it: AltGr+2 makes a ². Other than that, Java files upport Unicode. Just get the character somewhere from the Internet and copy/paste into your source file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert a special character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596164/how-to-insert-a-special-character)

Comment: The console only has one font, unlike HTML.  This means if you want super script you have to use different characters. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unicode code `u00B2` will give you the superscript two symbol. Try the following:

```
 System.out.println("km\u00B2");
```

[Working example](https://ideone.com/YVHZOP)

You could alternatively use the extended ASCII code `alt + 253` as stated [here](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/superscript-two-exponent-2-square-second-power-ascii-code-253.html)

Answer (score 4):

If your output is an **html** page:

```
km<sup>2</sup>
```

or

```
km&sup2;
```

If your output is a **String** to the console

```
System.out.println("km\u00B2");
```

**Other outputs**

If you need to print it to other systems (pdf, excel...) and they accept unicode values use the `char '\u00B2'` for the 2 at the exponent

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the "SUPERSCRIPT TWO" Unicode Character (escape code \u00B2) if your font supports it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string literal `"km\u00B2"`, or just use `km²` directly in your source code if you are using a unicode-supporting file encoding.